# bootstrap button associated with input control doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button associated to input control,On click i would like to call a function.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
<label for="fldVIN" >VIN</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="fldVIN" data-bind="value:VIN" class="form-control" placeholder="Search VIN to retrieve the details"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="searchVINBtn">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

and here is the sample script i tried but it doesn't invoke the click function.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
registerEventHandlers();
});

function registerEventHandlers(){
$('#searchVINBtn').click(function(e){
         getCRMorDMSDetails() ;
      });
});

function getCRMorDMSDetails()
            {
            alert('hi');                
            }
```

Comment: try getting a log into the click function to see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `)` after your `registerEventHandlers` function.

Your browser's error console would have pointed this out to you. **This should always be the first place you look.**

Working version:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    registerEventHandlers();
  });

  function registerEventHandlers() {
    $('#searchVINBtn').click(function(e) {
      getCRMorDMSDetails();
    });
  }; /* Remove ")" from this line */

  function getCRMorDMSDetails() {
    alert('hi');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
  <label for="fldVIN">VIN</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="fldVIN" data-bind="value:VIN" class="form-control" placeholder="Search VIN to retrieve the details" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="searchVINBtn">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
```